# Java - Custom Singly Linked List , Delete all occurrences of elements with a particular value

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, class, linked-list

I made a custom LinkedList in java, which is somewhat of a cross between a map & a list. I only did this exercise to learn, I know that HashMap is a better & faster implementation. I implemented delete method for LinkedList but am a little confused regarding which is the most optimal way to write method: deleteAll which basically deletes all occurences of a particular element.

Code:

```
public class LinkedListMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();

        System.out.println("isEmpty: " + linkedList.isEmpty());

        linkedList.insert("abc", 34);
        linkedList.insert("pqr", 44);
        linkedList.insert("xyz", 54);
        linkedList.insert("asd", 64);
        linkedList.insert("abc", 74);

        linkedList.print();

/*      System.out.println("delete: " + linkedList.delete("abc"));
        System.out.println("delete: " + linkedList.delete("pqr"));
        System.out.println("delete: " + linkedList.delete("xyz"));
        System.out.println("delete: " + linkedList.delete("asd"));
*/
        System.out.println("deleteAll: " + linkedList.deleteAll("abc"));
        System.out.println("isEmpty: " + linkedList.isEmpty());
    }
}

class LinkedList
{
    private ListNode first;
    private ListNode last;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
        last = first;
    }

    public void insert(String d1, int d2)
    {
        ListNode node = new ListNode(d1, d2);

        if(first == null)
        {
            node.next = null;
            first = node;
            last = node;
        }

        else
        {
            last.next = node;
            node.next = null;
            last = node;
        }
    }

    public String deleteAll(String str)
    {
        return "To Be Implemented";
    }

    public String delete(String str)
    {
        ListNode slow = first;
        ListNode fast = first;

        int count = 0;

        while(fast != null)
        {
            if(count > 1)
            {
                slow = slow.next;
            }

            if(count <= 1)
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(fast.getVal()==str)
            {
                if(fast == first)
                {
                    first = first.next;
                }

                else
                {
                    if(fast.next != null)
                    {
                        slow.next = fast.next;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        slow.next = null;
                    }
                }

                fast = null;
                return str;     // fast.getVal()
            }

            fast = fast.next;
        }

        return "not found";
    }

    public void print()
    {
        ListNode currentNode = first;

        while(currentNode != null)
        {
            currentNode.print();
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
//      return ( ((first==null) ? (true) : (false)) && ((last==null) ? (true) : (false)));
        return (first==null) ? (true) : (false);
    }
}

class ListNode
{
    private String data1;
    private int data2;

    public ListNode next;

    public ListNode(String d1, int d2)
    {
        data1 = d1;
        data2 = d2;
    }

    public String getVal()
    {
        return data1;
    }

//  public void printMe(ListNode node)
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("data1: [" + data1 + "], data2: [" + data2 + "]");
    }
}
```

I have 3 questions associated with this example:

1. Should the ideal deleteAll function repeatedly use my delete function? Should I make changes to my delete function to accommodate this?
2. Should the isEmpty function ideally compare first & last both to null? If last should be compared to null, then how should I change my delete & deleteAll functions for this to be implemented. I tried doing this with the current delete function but ran into some problems.
3. In general, can this code be optimized significantly? Not in the sense that "if you need the perfect linked list, use the Collections", simply asking how to exactly optimize this singly linked list more if possible?

Answer (score 1):

`deleteAll()` would probably be most comfortable to pass the *previous* node to a node deletion method. If `delete()` is expected to do anything but the obvious pointer manipulation, this action can be factored out.

```
/** 
 Deletes all nodes that contain target_string. 
 Returns the number of nodes deleted.
*/
public int deleteAll(String target_string) {
  int deleted_nodes_cnt = 0;
  ...
  if (prev_node.next.getVal().equals(target_string)) { // not ==
    deleteNextNode(prev_node); 
    prev_node = prev_node.next; 
    deleted_nodes_cnt += 1;
  }
  ...
  return deleted_nodes_cnt;
}

/** Delete the node after prev_node; prev_node.next != null */
private void deleteNextNode(Node prev_node) {
  Node dead_node = prev_node.next;
  prev_node.next = prev_node.next.next;
  dead_node.afterDelete(); // any custom cleanup, if required
}

public boolean delete(String target_string) {
   ... 

  if (prev_node.next.getVal().equals(target_string)) { // looks familiar?
    deleteNextNode(prev_node);
    return true; 
  }
  ...
  return false;
}
```

You may notice that `delete()` and `deleteAll()` use the same list iteration logic that can be nicely factored out, too.

```
/**
 Scan nodes, starting from this.
 Returns node X such that X.next.value equals target_string, or null. 
*/
private Node findNodeBeforeMatching(String target_string) {
  Node prev_node = this;
  while (prev_node.next != null) {
    if (prev_node.next.getVal().equals(target_string)) return prev_node;
    else prev_node = prev_node.next;
  }
  return null;
}
```

To use this method effectively, you will need to make `LinkedList` (essentially 'list head keeper') a subclass of `Node`, or make them both subclasses of a common class. Even better, make them implement the same interface which allows to `getNext()` and `deleteNext()`. Alternatively, you could return a `Node` from each operation, but this is not compatible with `Collection` interface, of course.

<sub>Old, incorrect text: `deleteAll()` should *not* call individual `delete()` methids, unless these methods may do something special in descendant classes . The reason is that such `deleteAll()` is O(1), runs in constant time, while traversing the list to `delete()` each node is O(n). AFAICT `last` instance variable serves only to speed up appending elements to the end of the list (though `insert()` does strange things to it). So `isEmpty()` should only really check `first`. If `first == null`, the method *may* `assert last == null`. I assume that having `first == null` but `last != null` means our bookkeeping was wrong, our data have been corrupted, and and we can't continue. WRT optimizing, I don't see how your byzantine `delete()` should work. I don't think having two pointers speed things up any in your case. Running two pointers with different 'speeds' is a known way to detect cycles, but I don't see how it's applicable here.</sub>

If you want a speed-up on *sorted* data, read about the [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), or use a tree. On unsorted data, a plain sequential scan is your best bet.

To me, an entire LinkedList class should be half as long, since it's so logically simple.

Your `ListNode` and `LinkedList` are unnecessarily tightly coupled in `insert()`, which should IMHO accept an instance, not construct it. Better yet, `ListNode` and `LinkedList` should be the same thing, as in classical implementations.

Get the [Wirth's book on data structures and algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130224189), it's very approachable. (When you have understood it fully, try to continue with Knuth's books, and if you're really brave, with Okasaki's book.)

Comment: deleteAll - as I mentioned in the post: deletes all occurences of a particular element. Example, deleteAll("xyz") will remove multiple xyz's, not all elements, hence it should be O(n). I kept fast & slow pointers so that if fast reaches xyz element, I can point slow.next (slow is running 1 slower than fast) to fast.next, & delete fast, so that the previous element points to the next one, otherwise I have to traverse once, find the position, then traverse again till one element before to do this. And, can you show code how to "accept an instance, not construct it" so that they are not "coupled"